# How to get the effective user id from inside the Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to find out the effective user id, from inside the docker. User uses my application which runs inside docker container. I want to get the euid (effective user id) of the user that uses my application. Using `id` will give me the euid of the user from non-docker environment. How can I get the euid from inside docker?

Comment: `id` should be right; a process in a container has no way of finding out what host user might be associated with it.  Do you have a more complete example to demonstrate the uid being wrong?

Comment: @DavidMaze why `id` should work inside docker? It does not know the users excited from outside docker

Comment: The process inside the container has an euid, and `id` will print it.  Do you mean something other than the user ID that, say, [geteuid(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/geteuid) returns?